# Using cups to print to windows domain with password in a separate file

Tags: windows, samba, printing, cups, cifs

Every guide I've seen so far that explains how to print to a Windows print server from CUPS, indicates to put the username and password, in plain text, in the Device URI either in the web interface (localhost:631) or in the /etc/cups/printers.conf

```
smb://user:password@hostname/printer
```

The trouble is my password contains spaces and special characters. When I attempt this, I still get NT authentication failures when printing test pages. I can connect via smbclient:

```
smbclient -L //ourprintserver01 -Uourdomain\\myusername
```

I've tried to create a `/etc/samba/printing.auth` file with the correct `username`, `password` and `domain` in it, as I've seen in some tutorials, but this still doesn't allow cups to properly authenticate. Is there a way to tell CUPS to use this file, or keep the password, username and domain in some other file cups can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create the printer, either through the web ui or via lpadmin with a URL with the special characters % encoded like this:

```
lpadmin -p fake -v smb://bob:pass%20word@rice/BLAH -P /tmp/foo.ppd
```

then the password will be stored in the /etc/cups/printers.conf file (which is readable only by root) and will *not* be displayed in the web UI.

Be careful though as if you accidentally enter a malformed URL then the cups web-ui won't be able to figure out which bit is the password and it will be displayed.

Comment: Do I have to URL-encode the `\ ` separating the user name and the domain? So should I assume it must be `domain%5Cbob` or `domain\bob`?

Comment: No idea. try it and report back?

Comment: You can enter the domain like this:
`smb://DOMAIN\user:password@foo/bar` without further encoding.

Comment: Useful detail: %20 is the hexadecimal code for the ASCII space.  Other characters you may have to encode are the hash (# = %23) and percent itself (% = %25).  Other characters can be found in ASCII tables, like this one: https://www.ascii-code.com/